# Generate asciidoctor doc with spring rest docs using maven (not gradle)

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, spring-restdocs

With gradle to generate asciidoctor documentation you need to `gradle asciidoctor` in comand line and the documentation is generated by this task.

With maven I can generate the asciidoctor documentation with `mvn package`. But this packages all the project. Is there a way to use `mvn` just to generate the documentation without package all the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Usually in Maven the *documentation* generation/packaging is bound to the `site` lifecycle, that means it will be created when running `mvn site`.

Here is an example with Javadoc how to bind a plugin to the `site` phase:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <phase>site</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      ...
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

You can also directly use the [asciidoctor-maven-plugin](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>{release-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(taken from the [asciidoctor documentation](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin#maven-site-integration))